# Rotating CALayer of NSImageView 90 degrees

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-animation

I am trying to rotate the CALayer of an NSImageView.  My problem is that the anchorPoint appears to be (0.0, 0.0) by default but I want it to be the center of the image (Apple's documentation indicates the default should be the center (0.5, 0.5), but it's not on my system OS X 10.7), When I modify the anchor point the origin of the center of the image shifts to the lower left corner.

Here's the code I am using to rotate the layer:

```
CALayer *myLayer = [imageView layer];
CGFloat myRotationAngle = -M_PI_2;

NSNumber *rotationAtStart = [myLayer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
CATransform3D myRotationTransform = CATransform3DRotate(myLayer.transform, myRotationAngle, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
myLayer.transform = myRotationTransform;        
CABasicAnimation *myAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
myAnimation.duration = 1.0;
myAnimation.fromValue = rotationAtStart;
myAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:([rotationAtStart floatValue] + myRotationAngle)];
[myLayer addAnimation:myAnimation forKey:@"transform.rotation"];

myLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
[myLayer addAnimation:myAnimation forKey:@"transform.rotation"];
```

Comment: It appears that if I move the anchorPoint code to the awakeFromNib then the origin doesn't appear to change... I think there's something I'm missing with respects to my understanding of CoreAnimation

Comment: Your code listing is incomplete (especially since you mention moving things to -awakeFromNib). Please post all relevant code, including exactly where all this is being called. Also explain how the view hosting this layer tree is created (from a nib, from -initWithFrame:, how?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that changing the anchor point of something also changes it's position.  The following snippet fixes the problem:

```
  CGPoint anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
  CGPoint newPoint = CGPointMake(disclosureTriangle.bounds.size.width * anchorPoint.x, 
                                 disclosureTriangle.bounds.size.height * anchorPoint.y);
  CGPoint oldPoint = CGPointMake(disclosureTriangle.bounds.size.width * disclosureTriangle.layer.anchorPoint.x, 
                                 disclosureTriangle.bounds.size.height * disclosureTriangle.layer.anchorPoint.y);

  newPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(newPoint, 
                                         [disclosureTriangle.layer affineTransform]);
  oldPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(oldPoint,
                                         [disclosureTriangle.layer affineTransform]);

  CGPoint position = disclosureTriangle.layer.position;

  position.x -= oldPoint.x;
  position.x += newPoint.x;

  position.y -= oldPoint.y;
  position.y += newPoint.y;

  disclosureTriangle.layer.position = position;
  disclosureTriangle.layer.anchorPoint = anchorPoint;
```